# JFace question: How do I select all items in a ListSelectionDialog?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I create a JFace ListSelectionDialog as follows.

```
final ListSelectionDialog dialog = new ListSelectionDialog(
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().getActiveShell(),
        List<SomeClass>,
        new ArrayContentProvider(), 
        new LabelProvider(), 
        ""); //$NON-NLS-1$

dialog.setTitle("Dialog Title"); //$NON-NLS-1$
dialog.setMessage("SomeMessage"); //$NON-NLS-1$
dialog.open();
```

and the dialog shows up fine.

However, I'd like all the checkboxes to be selected.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List elementsToSelect = ...
dialog.setInitialElementSelections(elementsToSelect);
```

Comment: Just figured it out myself too :P Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the ListSelectionDialog and add this method:

```
public void selectAll() {
    getViewer().setAllChecked(true);
}
```